# How can one import existing vSphere virtual machines into vRealize Automation 8.0?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, automation, import, bulk-action

I have a number of existing virtual machines within my vSphere datacenter. These VMs were not created using our vRealize 8 blueprints etc. However, I want to add the VMs to the vRA 8 inventory so that my users, who do not have access to vSphere, can have the ability to power them off/on, do basic reconfiguration, etc.

I believe the way to do this with vRA 7 was via a bulk import, but I can't for the life of me work out how to do such a thing on vRA 8. I know VMware changed the names of a lot of things, so hopefully the functionality is still there but is hidden away.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I've figured out where the option is. Under Cloud Assembly, choose Infrastructure -> **Onboarding**, then create a new onboarding plan and rules based on the machine hostnames.

It seems like this is no longer referred to at all as Bulk Import, or even Import, which is why I had such trouble working out where it lived.